# OpenCL dynamic parallelism / GPU-spawned threads?

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

CUDA 5 [has just been released](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Releases-CUDA-5-Making-Programming-With-World-s-Most-Pervasive-Parallel-Computing-Platform-Even-Easier-88b.aspx) and with it the ability to spawn GPU threads from within another GPU (main?) thread, minimising callouts between CPU and GPU that we've seen thus far.

What plans are there to support GPU-spawned threads in the OpenCL arena? As I cannot afford to opt for a closed standard (my user base is "everygamer"), I need to know when OpenCL is ready for prime time in this regard.

Comment: This feature requires yet to be released hardware (the Kepler GK110). So although the feature exists in the toolchain, there isn't currently any hardware which supports it.

Comment: Sure; but the question is, "What is the status of plans for support of this in OpenCL?"

Comment: @talonmies In case that was you, or to whoever else did so: I would like to understand why this question was downvoted, please. I am asking someone who knows the spec, to provide info.

Comment: If you user base is "everygamer" and you don't want to be tied to a proprietary system, isn't it a contradictory to be asking about a feature of a single manufacturer's yet to be released $2000+ compute device? Further, this question requires speculation about the content and timing of future versions of the OpenCL standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCL Standard is usually the way back of CUDA (except for device partitioning feature) and I guess this feature will be added to OpenCL in a year.

EDIT on Aug 8, 2013: This feature has been introduced in [OpenCL 2.0](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-releases-opencl-2.0).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, as AMD does not support dynamic parallelism in the same way NVIDIA does.

Comment: @KLee1 This thread can have interesting discussions. If we back to previous years we see that whatever NVIDIA (or AMD) offers the other offers too soon. For example, and maybe the biggest one, AMD traditionally used VLIW architecture for SMs. However, latest AMD GPUs employ scalar SMs similar too NVIDIA. There are many other of these examples like concurrent kernels, DVFS, and so on.

Comment: those changes may be true, but I'm not sure if you can use the past as a way to predict the future in this case.  AMD may adopt dynamic parallelism soon, but it may also not.

Comment: You have a valid point @KLee1, the past isn't a good way to predict the future. However, I see the dynamic parallelism to be a game changer. AMD (and OpenCL for that matter) have to follow suit or they are dead in the water with regards to HPC and the GPGPU market.